# text not showing in my listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

obviously i am doing something wrong as I have used this type of control in this way before.

My text is not displaying in my listview. I can double click the item and get its value(s) but I cannot see it. You would think it would be a simple style setting and maybe it has been set elsewhere in my appp.xaml but it is not.

This is my markup:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="myHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="value1Template">
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=CustomerName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>


<ListView x:Name="lstActiveJobs" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Black" MouseDoubleClick="lstActiveJobs_MouseDoubleClick" >
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="View"
                        Click="cmView"     
                        Command="{Binding RemoveItem}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, 
                       Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />                   
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}">
            <GridViewColumn Header="CustomerName"  Width="100"  CellTemplate="{StaticResource value1Template}"  />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"  />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

part of my code behind:

```
lstActiveJobs.ItemsSource = ActiveState.JobsActive;

public static ObservableCollection<JobTicker> JobsActive = new ObservableCollection<JobTicker>();
```

point to note is:

```
ActiveState.JobsActive does have a record/item
```

My Model:

```
public  class JobTicker
{
    public string CustomerRef;
    public string JobRef;
    public string CustomerName;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field is not a valid [binding source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743643(v=vs.100).aspx#binding_sources)

> You can bind to public properties, sub-properties, as well as indexers, of any common language runtime (CLR) object.

so you need to convert your fields into properties

```
public class JobTicker
{
    public string CustomerRef { get; set; }
    public string JobRef { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ha yes. I remember now.  I had that issue in a MVC web api did before.  Teach me to be lazy writing my POCOs.  Guess I need to buy re-sharper. thanks